# Register Author Type user in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I am using wp_create_user function to register new user in wordpress.
This function is inserting user as a role of subscriber. I want to insert users as a author type role. How can i do this.?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

The wp_create_user() function returns the ID of the user it creates. You can then use the WP_User class like:

```
$new_user_id = wp_create_user($your_args_here);

$u = new WP_User( $new_user_id );

// Remove role
$u->remove_role( 'subscriber' );

// Add role
$u->add_role( 'author' );
```

Alternatively, you can use [wp_update_user()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_update_user) function:

Although I'm not *precisely* sure how to do that, but I imagine you could work it out by looking in wp-includes/registration.php which is where that function is created.